# Q: Promise Chaining and Rejection: Doesn't reject kill the chain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I have the following chained functions that all implement promises utilizing Q:

```
validateToken(context).then(parseFormData, get403).then(createReport, get400).then(send200, get400).catch(get500);
```

e.g. All of them have somewhere within them:

```
let deferred = q.defer();
..
deferred.resolve(true);
deferred.reject(false);
return deferred.promise;
```

The first function validateToken calls a deferred.reject. This then results with get403 being called, as expected; but createReport, get400 and get500 are also being called? This confuses me. I thought only the first error handler was hit in the chain?

Can someone please explain what is happening, and if there is a way for me to get the desired behavior where only the most immediate reject/error handler is called?

Comment: Does `get403` reject or throw an error?

Comment: No, get403 does NOT reject or throw an error. Based on Leroy's response below, it sounds like that is key and I misunderstood the way chaining works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what `on403` returns.  If nothing, it is assumed to be a resolve - which explains the behavior you are seeing.  Remember, `onReject` is equivalent to a `catch`, which, as a concept, *allows you to continue processing as if an error didn't happen*

If you want to continue down the reject chain then you have to `return Promise.reject()`.  Otherwise you have to rethink your promise chaining.

Comment: Interesting, so if my reject handler doesn't return a reject as well it will continue down the chain? I didn't realize that. I'll have to play around with this.

Comment: Thank-you. This definitely worked. I don't know how I got the wrong understanding of how the chaining works; but this is a very simple explanation. If you know of any resources that talk about this in more detail that would probably make this answer even better, but it works for me! Thanks again!

Comment: Honestly there are a million resources online that talk about how Promise chaining works, and specifically the MDN documentation (pretty much the *de facto* documentation for all things javascript related) covers it well https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise